# Multi-deployment scale k8s

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, microservices

I've explored k8s, yet couldn't find an answer to a not trivial setup I have.

I have 2 apps (2 containers) which work together but not related.
`app1` receives and filters data, then sends to `app2`.

1. I've decided to have `deployment` per application;
   1.1. (And not both containers reside in the same `POD`) because they shouldn't share anything - communication take place on standard network.
   1.2. Each could scale independently

-> **Q1** is this approach correct ?

So I have 2 deployments corresponding to these 2 apps. Defined in `deployment1.yaml` and `deployment2.yaml`.
Each could scale independently with `kubectl scale`.

My two deployments should work together, so in case of scale I would like to:

2. Scale both `deployment1` and `deployment2`

-> **Q2** Is there a way to perform multi deployment scale with `k8s` ?

3. Do something for the newly created instance of `deployment1` so it would know of new instance of `deployment2` existence (ip address, etc...). i.e. I would like to send some request to it with `deployment2` ip.

-> **Q3** Is there a way to have some kind of hook for `after-successful-scale` in order to run some code? e.g. bash script? If there is - who runs it? the master node? Some init container?

Regardless of `3.` I would like also `deployment1` to pull its configuration from somewhere when it starts. Or alternatively somehow attach files to it when it starts.

-> **Q4** Is there a way to do it dynamically? First instance of `deployment1` might have different configuration than the second instance. I understand I might use [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) instead of [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) so I would recognize unique instance.
I thought of using some shared volume / ConfigMap so all instances would read their own unique configuration with their instance number. But I also thought there's a more standard way to do it, so I ask.

---

I thought what is the way to perform these requirements in the trivial setup of web apps, and thought:

1. Both `deployments` scale automatically when need to according to some trigger.
2. Both `deployments` export a LoadBalancer, so `app1` always talks to `app2`'s LoadBalancer - then `deployment1` is really independent from `deployment2`; both scale and LoadBalancer handles the load.

-> **Q5** Is that thought correct for the trivial case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more I look at it, the more I understand `K8S` directly isn't the answer to my requirements.

I'm implementing a `VNF` so I need another layer of abstraction.
Currently I'm looking at [OSM](https://osm.etsi.org/) which from couple of first glances looks like it has what I need.

I'll try to update after I know more.

Answer (score 2):

For q5: Just create a Service, let the applications talk inside the kubernetes cluster and the Service will handle load balancing (per request). You don't need a Service of type `LoadBalancer` and make the applications use an external IP.

q1-q4: You can write your own operator using the kubernetes API (and probably client libraries). There is a watch API so you cat notified automatically of changes that are relevant for your operator, so you don't have to poll.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 & 2: You can use two deployments, A and B, and two services, svcA and svcB to expose the pods. That way, A can simply refer to B using the name 'svcB'.

Do you really need to know if a new instance of pod created? Because if there are multiple instances of pod B is running, then the service `svcB` will act as a load balancer, and distribute the load among the instances of B.

For storing configurations, use a ConfigMap, and mount to configmap in your deployment for A and B. However, this will give you identical configurations for all instances of pods.

If you *really* need to know which particular pod you're working with, you can use stateful sets instead of deployments. The hostname will include the pod id, so you can distinguish between different instances.

Comment: `1,2` - The thing is, `app1` talks to `app2` with ip (it sends data with on gre). `app2` listens on the interface in promiscuous mode, it doesn't open standard listen socket. Because of that I cannot do some kind of "Service export" and hope 'svcB' will distribute the load to all instances of `app2`.

Comment: Looks like a really strange design choice to me, what is the reason for promisc mode?

Comment: If you are listening packets using promiscuous mode, I'd question the rationale to deploy this app on k8s. You are dealing with an SDN, and things change a lot in the underlying fabric.

Comment: @BurakSerdar yes, I'm coming to a conclusion that I need something like OSM - open source mano, which orchestrates VNFs, instead of directly using k8s. But I'm still investigating.